# How To Set Date Range In Symfony DateType Field?

Tags: symfony

I Need To set Range on Minimum and maximum date on dateType field in Form. My Code is here.

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('date',DateType::Class, array(
        'widget' => 'single_text',
        'attr' => array(
            'min' => new \DateTime(),
            'max' => new \DateTime('+7 day'),
    )));
}
```

Comment: Do you want drop-down lists or just a single field input? Normally you need to handle month, day and year.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
       $builder->add('date',DateType::Class, array(
                 'widget' => 'choice',
                 'years' => range(date('Y'), date('Y')+100),
                 'months' => range(date('m'), 12),
                 'days' => range(date('d'), 31),
               ));
 }
```

Comment: Sorry for responding for such old answer. I am very curious how to add date range limits but when 'widget' is set to 'single_text', 'html5' set to false and you use i.e.  Bootstrap datepicker. Could you somehow limit date range? Symfony doc's only says you can use 'years', 'months' and 'days' with 'widget' set to 'choice'...

Comment: This is incorrect answer, because according to the official documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#years "years" parameter works only when `'widget' => 'choice'` and in the example of the author it's `'widget' => 'single_text'`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you'll get an error because you've set `min` and `max` attributes as DateTime object instead of text. Convert they to string (use `format()` method). Something like this:

```
'min' => (new \DateTime())->format('c'), //use format you need
```