# how to desactivate dates from current day above

Tags: symfony, date, twig, formbuilder

I have a birth date that user should pick (the user shouls have at least 21 years old), how can desactivate dates and let him can't choose a date newer than 21 years.

(I cant use @Assert\LessThan("-21 years") in my entity because it causes another problem form me)

Is it doable from the buildForm? if it is please help me

I am using formbuilder to create my form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{   ->add('datebirth', DateType::class, [
            'label' => 'common.label.datbirth',
            'widget' => 'single_text', 'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd'
        ])
```

}

Answer (score 0):

[How to set date range in symfony datetype field :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41521276/how-to-set-date-range-in-symfony-datetype-field)

From [@se_developer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4550278/se-developers)

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
       $builder->add('datebirth',DateType::Class, array(
                 'widget' => 'single_text',
                 'years' => range(date('Y'), date('Y')+100),
                 'months' => range(date('m'), 12),
                 'days' => range(date('d'), 31),
               ));
 }
```